# DataStore in UML Class Diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am doing UML class diagram for the first time. I have put a data store in class diagram I am not sure if I can . Also, is it possible to get feedback on this class diagram I have uploaded?

Basically its a hotel management system.

I am explaining the story point wise here. I have removed the unwanted stuffs from the story.

1) Login - Allow user to search room if he is a registered user. If  not he/she should be able to register to hotel management system.

2)User should be able to search the available rooms from the system and select a type of room-Available rooms based on check in and check out dates.

3)Hotel employee should be able to charge for the facilities availed.

4)Store user information for marketing Purposes.

5)User should be able to cancel made reservation of rooms.

6)Make payments online.

7)User/receptionist should be able to modify/update rooms booked, User information from the information they have. - I added data store.

[image]

Comment: A bit layout would be nice (esp. Payment). But if you need critique you need to tell what you **wanted** so we can see whether it's expressed right.

Comment: One more thing I am calling datastore() operation in some classes ? Is this the right way to do ? Indicating updating database.

Comment: Unless you get down to telling a few more details you will not get meaningful answers.

Comment: @ThomasKilian -Updated

Comment: Ok. I'll have a look when I'm back later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Placing login method in the class which gains login does not seem to be reasonable. Authorization should be a class of its own and a user may gain access through it.
2. There is nothin modeled which shows the occupation of rooms. I'd expect some Occupation class which links rooms to time ranges.
3. The same. What is the basis for the occupation? There needs to be an Occupation class which relates Room with time frames.
4. What are marketing purposes? You could implement some user statistics that traces when a user has booked rooms, how punctual he paid, etc. Those are not modeled.
5. Since you have not modeled a Reservation you will not be able to cancel it.
6. The Payment is related to nothing. So you don't know for what a payment was made. Your book keeping will love you for that :-(
7. As above: no reservation modeled - no modification possible.

You should probably find some mentor to sit together and do some basic modeling.

**Edit** (as on the updated model): This is not the way to go. The datastore will serialize the single objects, and not be a class of its own. The way you need to do it is to construct a model with the relevant classes. Those will finally result in persistent objects in the database. FacilityAvailed does not look sensible. This looks like information you can compute from Reservation (which needs a relation to Room which is now missing completely). Well, you should dump this approach and start all over. Just model the business objects (BO): Room, Reservation, User, Payment, etc. Relate those meaningful. What are the attribute of each BO (Room: Number, Size, Cost,... User:Role, Name, ...). Then try to relate them. E.g. a Reservation may relate Room and User, but could also be simply for refurbishment/cleaning etc.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have made a quick update since it was going no where. Not making any more changes to original diagram. I will put a updated version next to it if I can.

Comment: You may as well start a new question :-)

Comment: Can you make a quick comment on the above if your free / update your answer ?

Comment: I changed the class diagram up there 

Comment: Oh, I see. It just looked the same blue on a first glance. Will have a look.

Comment: I have added an edit. Please avoid extending this to go into a teaching session. Try asking a new question with a new approach.